# What is the time complexity of my solutions?

Tags: java, performance

First method:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> applicationPairs(int deviceCapacity, List<List<Integer>> foregroundAppList, List<List<Integer>> backgroundAppList) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (List<Integer> foregroundApp : foregroundAppList) {
            for (List<Integer> backgroundApp : backgroundAppList) {
                int memoryRequired = foregroundApp.get(1) + backgroundApp.get(1);
                
                if (memoryRequired <= deviceCapacity) {
                    if (memoryRequired > max) {
                        result.clear();
                        max = memoryRequired;
                        result.add(Arrays.asList(foregroundApp.get(0), backgroundApp.get(0)));
                    } else if (memoryRequired == max) {
                        result.add(Arrays.asList(foregroundApp.get(0), backgroundApp.get(0)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*
            return empty pair if no pair is found
         */
        if (result.size() == 0) {
           return new ArrayList<>(Collections.emptyList()); 
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Second method:

```
public static List<String> sortOrders(List<String> orderList) {
        // Write your code here
        var result = orderList.stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.split(" ")[1].matches("[a-z]+"))
                        .sorted((s, t1) -> {
                            int r = s.substring(s.indexOf(" ")).compareTo(t1.substring(t1.indexOf(" ")));

                            if (r == 0) {
                                return s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")).compareTo(t1.substring(0, t1.indexOf(" ")));
                            }
                            return r;
                        })//.thenComparing(s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" "))))
                        .collect(toList());
        return Stream.concat(result.stream(), orderList.stream().filter(e -> !result.contains(e)))
                     .collect(toList());
    }
```

I was asked to write these solutions as amazon's online assessment thing. Question also said to write the time complexity of the solutions, which I am not good at calculating.
Anyone?

Comment: what are you talking about? that filter(e -> !result.contains(e)) is for orderList stream

Comment: Sorry, I misread the parentheses. Though the performance can still be improved. Change `result` to a `LinkedHashSet` using `collect(toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))`, then just do `result.addAll(orderList); return result;`. That will change performance from _O(n²)_ to _O(n)_. If the return value must be a list, use `return new ArrayList<>(result);`.

Comment: When `result.size() == 0`, which is the same as `result.isEmpty()`, the variable `result`  does already refer to an empty `ArrayList`. So what’s the point of `new ArrayList<>(Collections.emptyList())` that does nothing but construct an empty `ArrayList`, like you already have, but in an inefficient way? Besides that, this nested loop is entirely unnecessary. Unless overflow occurs, the sum has the same relation as the summands. Just find the max value(s) of either list, then combine them, as their sum will be the max sum either. And the second operation can be done as a single sort operation.

Comment: @Andreas when you eliminate the O(n²), the sort operation still has O(n log n). But I agree that eliminating the O(n²) has the highest priority. But the whole operation can be done as a single sort operation using the predicate’s condition as primary sort criteria and the other as secondary.

Comment: @Holger, the question asked that in case of empty list return something like ```[ [ () ] ]```, if i removed that ```if block``` my solution couldn't pass all the available test cases. And its not just about getting the sum of maximum of each list, the sum also has to be less than or equals to ```deviceCapacity``` and there can be more than one pair with equal sum.

Comment: Then, there’s a fundamental problem with your test cases. Just try `System.out.println(new ArrayList<>(Collections.emptyList()).equals(new ArrayList<>()));` It will print `true`, as passing a list to `ArrayList`’s constructor does not add the list as an element to the list, but initializes the list to have the same contents, i.e. an empty list in your case. So `return new ArrayList<>( Collections.emptyList());` just returns an empty list, like `return result;` would do in that case.

Comment: @Holger okay this is what i actually did ```var r = new ArrayList<>();  r.add(new ArrayList<>()); ``` When posting here i changed it i don't know why. If you print ```r``` you will see.

Comment: Ok. If returning `ArrayList` instances is not a requirement, you could simplify it to `return Collections.singletonList(Collections.emptyList());` Perhaps, you had something like this in mind when you made the change.

Comment: @Holger hey can you show me how to do the second method as single sort? I tried ```Comparator.comparing().thenComparing()``` but the IDE was flaging that as an error.

Comment: The `thenComparing` approach can’t express the logic correctly, as apparently, you don’t want to change the order of the elements not matching `e.split(" ")[1].matches("[a-z]+")`. But first, I need a clarification. Is the intended meaning of the condition that “everything after the first space must match `[a-z]+`” or “everything between the first and second space must match `[a-z]+`”?

Comment: @Holger strings in orderList has the format: "identifier prime/non-prime_indicator product". If the indicator  is Alphabetic then the product is prime otherwise it's non-prime. Result set should have prime products at the top and they should be sorted by substring excluding identifier. In case two products are same sort them by their identifier. Non-prime orders should be below the prime and their order must be same as they originally were.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233560/discussion-between-holger-and-s-v).

Answer (score 1):

In the first method if you see you are iterating over two lists, `foregroundAppList`, and `backgroundAppList`. As you are iterating each element `backgroundAppList` per element if `foregroundAppList`, it's clearly a time complexity of `O(n*m)` Where n is the size of `backgroundAppList` and `m` is the size of `foregroundAppList`.

In the second method, you have implemented a custom sort method and as you might be aware the Java `sorted` method uses Quicksort for list of primitives and merge sort for list of objects, where in both the cases the average time complexity fall under `O(n*log(n))` where `n` is the size of the list.

Comment: The second method’s `orderList.stream().filter(e -> !result.contains(e))` has O(n²) which dwarves the sorting algorithm’s time complexity. Further, the generic `Stream` and in fact every standard API supporting a custom comparator uses Timsort, a Mergesort variant, never Quicksort. Also note that the OP’s comparator uses `indexOf` and `substring`, both having linear time complexity regarding the average string length.